# Did De Niro and Pacino actually meet during The Godfather II shooting?

Tags: casting, the-godfather-2

Al Pacino and Robert De Niro don't play together in the same scene as De Niro plays young adult Vito and Pacino plays adult Michael.

Have they met out stage, behind the scenes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes

At least once.

Publicity images were issued featuring the two actors together.

[image][image]

Comment: Oh, Paulie... I didn't think we'd see you no more!